# How to get the File's Content Type in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, content-type, file-extension

I know the file's name, that is saved on server, I want to get the `contentType` of that file that is saved on server, what I want is something like this:

```
string loc = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/document.*");
```

But the above code is not working and the error says :

> Illegal character is specified i.e.(*)

My question is, how to get the extension and the content type of the file name that I know and is saved on server?

Comment: Once stored on the disk, there's no longer a notion of `ContentType`. So basically you could associate this information with the file by the time it gets uploaded and persist it in your datastore. Then just look at the datastore the corresponding ContentType given a filename. On the other hand if all you need is the file extension, then this is quite easy using the [Path.GetExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: @darin said absolutely marvelous answer. A shortest and fastest solution of what u asked for.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov That's the answer, can you let me mark it as the answer?

Comment: Check This: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/HttpPostedFileBase-getting-file-extension-in-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for the file `extension` or the `content-type` (mime-type) of the file?

If you are looking for the file extension you can use [Path.GetExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(Server.MapPath("a.txt"));
// returns ".txt"
```

If you are looking for file **mime type** make use of [MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var mimeType  = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("a.txt");
// returns "plain/text"
```